# VBScript Outlook Signature cell padding

Tags: vbscript, outlook, ms-word, signature

I'm creating an automated Outlook signature that gets data from AD. All's going well, but I keep getting whitespace (looks like padding or something) on table cells.

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" + strUser)

strName = objUser.givenName
strSurName = objUser.Sn
strFullName = objUser.Fullname
strTitle = objUser.Title
strAdres = objUser.address
strPhone = objUser.TelephoneNumber
strMob = objUser.Mobile
strEmail = objUser.mail
strMarBoo = objUser.StreetAddress
strMarLinkTxt = objUser.postOfficeBox
strMarLink = objUser.l
strDescription = objUser.Description
strIT = ""

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature

Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

objSelection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 14
objSelection.TypeText "Met vriendelijke groet, "
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
'objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(240,73,6)
objSelection.Font.Bold = True
objSelection.TypeText strFullName
objSelection.Font.Bold = False
objSelection.TypeText Chr(11)
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(47,84,150)
objSelection.Font.Size = 11

objSelection.TypeText strTitle + Chr(11)
objSelection.Font.Size = 11
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(47,84,150)
Set objRange = objSelection.Range
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 3, 5

Set objTable1 = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable1.TopPadding = PixelsToPoints(10, True)
objTable1.BottomPadding = PixelsToPoints(10, True)

'Merge cells in col 1
objTable1.Columns(1).Cells.Merge

objTable1.Columns(1).PreferredWidth = 90
objTable1.Columns(2).PreferredWidth = 100
objTable1.Columns(3).PreferredWidth = 150
objTable1.Columns(4).PreferredWidth = 100
objTable1.Columns(5).PreferredWidth = 200

'----------------KOLOM 1------------------------------
objTable1.Cell(1,1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "\\int-vm-    pdc\NETLOGON\logo_rondje_oranje_small.png"

'----------------KOLOM 2------------------------------
objTable1.Cell(1,2).Range.Font.Bold = True
objTable1.Cell(1,2).Range.Font.Color = RGB(240,73,6)
objTable1.Cell(2,2).Range.Font.Bold = True
objTable1.Cell(2,2).Range.Font.Color = RGB(240,73,6)
objTable1.Cell(3,2).Range.Font.Bold = True
objTable1.Cell(3,2).Range.Font.Color = RGB(240,73,6)

objTable1.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "Bezoekadres"
objTable1.Cell(2,2).Range.Text = "Hoofdnummer"
objTable1.Cell(3,2).Range.Text = "Rechtstreeks"

'----------------KOLOM 3------------------------------
objTable1.Cell(1,3).Range.Text = strAdres
objTable1.Cell(2,3).Range.Text = strPhone
objTable1.Cell(3,3).Range.Text = strMob

'----------------KOLOM 4------------------------------
objTable1.Cell(1,4).Range.Font.Bold = True
objTable1.Cell(1,4).Range.Font.Color = RGB(240,73,6)
objTable1.Cell(2,4).Range.Font.Bold = True
objTable1.Cell(2,4).Range.Font.Color = RGB(240,73,6)    
objTable1.Cell(3,4).Range.Font.Bold = True
objTable1.Cell(3,4).Range.Font.Color = RGB(240,73,6)

objTable1.Cell(1,4).Range.Text = "Emailadres"
objTable1.Cell(2,4).Range.Text = "Website"

'----------------KOLOM 5------------------------------
Set objCell = objTable1.Cell(1,5).Range
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objCell, "mailto:"&strEmail, , ,strEmail)

Set objCell = objTable1.Cell(2,5).Range
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objCell, "https://www.company.com", , ,"https://www.company.com")

objTable1.Cell(3,5).Range.Text = strDescription

objSelection.EndKey 6

With Selection.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBefore = 0
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfter = 0
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
End With

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()

objSignatureEntries.Add "Handtekening_2018_extended", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "Handtekening_2018_extended"
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "Handtekening_2018_extended"

objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit
```

See image for a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Already tried setting `Font.LineHeight`, `objTable1.Rows(1).Height`, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Maybe there is some more detailed documentation that I cannot find about styling?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Your code here is not complete; I don't see where you've assigned `objDoc`, for example.

Comment: There are various possibilities, table cell padding or paragraph Space Before and/or Space After or even paragraph Line Height. To really find out what's happening you'd need to inspect all the possible properties in the dialog box interfaces. My first suspect would be the paragraph formatting, followed by the cell padding.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot seem to change this. Reset line height, cell padding etc, but no changes...